# Reference of Nested document in other schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a customer schema which is referring to the user schema. the customer schema is having members which is an array like below

```
 var CustomerSchema = new Schema({
  user:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
   },
   members:[ {       
        fname: {
            type: String,                
        },
        lname: {
            type: String,                
        }
     }
   ],
 });
```

I also have a jobschema now I want to refer the members to the job schema. How can I do it is there any way to refer member objectId() ( which will be generated when you insert values to members in the customer schema) in the jobschema.
My JobSchema will look like

```
   var JobSchema = new Schema({
    user:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
    },
    task[{
      members:[{
            member_id:{
               type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
               ref: 'Customer.members'
             }
       }]
     }]
```

I have to refer members inside the task

Comment: I also had the same problem in one of my project.  I had to create another schema for members and store their _id into members array of customer and refer them to member schema. so that i can refer members anywhere. Wish you luck to solve out this problem with same schema. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in this way by defining `job` field and make it reference to your job schema.In this way you can refer member in job

**CUSTOMER SCHEMA**

```
 var Customer = new Schema({
      user:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,  ref: 'User' },
      members:[ {       
            fname: String,
            lname: String,
            job: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Job'} 
       }],
     });

 module.exports = mongoose.model('Customer', Customer);
```

**JOB  SCHEMA**

```
var Job = new Schema({
        text: String
 });
  module.exports = mongoose.model('Job', Job);
```

Comment: I want members to be referred in jobs. what you are saying the opposite of that

Comment: what is your requirement ? its `one to many` or `many to many`